# Conditional vlookup in bash with awk or sed?

Tags: bash, awk

I have those two files (both have headers), each line of both files are starting with a date on the first column with the same format. the separator is a semicolon.

On the 9th column of the first file, I can only have those id: UK or JPN or EUR.

I need to aggregate file1 with the intel from file2 with the corresponding date intel.

I can try to do it with a bash script and a "for" loop of course, but I'm sure that resource wise it will be better with an awk or else bash command... if possible!

Thanks in advance for any hint.

ps: I tried unsuccessfully to adapt this method: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/428861/vlookup-equivalent-in-awk-scripting

The first file :

```
Date;$2;$3;$4;$5;$6;$7;$8;Id
2018-01-01;              ;UK
2018-01-02;              ;JPN
2018-01-03;              ;EUR
2018-01-04;              ;JPN
```

the second file :

```
Date;UKDIR;JPNDIR;EURDIR

2018-01-01;1;2;3           
2018-01-02;4;5;6              
2018-01-03;7;8;9
2018-01-04;11;10;12
```

Expected return

```
Date;$2;$3;$4;$5;$6;$7;$8;Id  ;Intel
2018-01-01;              ;UK  ;1
2018-01-02;              ;JPN ;5
2018-01-03;              ;EUR ;9
2018-01-04;              ;JPN ;10
```

Comment: In the last record it should be `2018-01-04;              ;JPN ;10` right?

Comment: Exactly ! sorry for that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk -F';' -v OFS='; ' 'NR==1 { for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) h[i]=$i; next }
   FNR==NR { for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) a[$1,h[i]]=$i; next }
   FNR==1 { print $0, "Intel"; next }
   { print $0, a[$1,$NF "DIR"] }' file2 file1
```

```
Date;$2;$3;$4;$5;$6;$7;$8;Id; Intel
2018-01-01;              ;UK; 1
2018-01-02;              ;JPN; 5
2018-01-03;              ;EUR; 9
2018-01-04;              ;JPN; 10
```

Comment: Thanks but OP has to confirm that first :)

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  count=count1=1
  FS=OFS=";"
}
FNR!=NR && FNR==1{
  print $0 OFS "Intel"
}
FNR==NR && /^[0-9]/{
  a[$1]=$(++count)
  count=count==4?1:count
  next
}
NF && /^[0-9]/{
  print $0 OFS a[$1]
  count1=count1==4?1:count1
}
' second_file  first_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Date;$2;$3;$4;$5;$6;$7;$8;Id;Intel
2018-01-01;              ;UK;1
2018-01-02;              ;JPN;5
2018-01-03;              ;EUR;9
2018-01-04;              ;JPN;11
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" }
NR==FNR {
    if (NR == 1) {
        for (fldNr=2; fldNr<=NF; fldNr++) {
            fldName = $fldNr
            sub(/DIR/,"",fldName)
            fldNr2name[fldNr] = fldName
        }
    }
    else {
        for (fldNr=2; fldNr<=NF; fldNr++) {
            fldName = fldNr2name[fldNr]
            dateFldName2val[$1,fldName] = $fldNr
        }
    }
    next
}
{
    print $0, (FNR>1 ? dateFldName2val[$1,$NF] : "Intel")
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
Date;$2;$3;$4;$5;$6;$7;$8;Id;Intel
2018-01-01;              ;UK;1
2018-01-02;              ;JPN;5
2018-01-03;              ;EUR;9
2018-01-04;              ;JPN;10
```